# Updating a row of a matrix in rust ndarray

Tags: rust, rust-ndarray

I was looking to update a row of 2D matrix in rust ndarray, but `row_mut` does not seem to allow me to update the row directly.

For example ([playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3419f8cd09b8f68bf5db58788f1a57e0))

```
let mut array = array![[1., 2.], [3., 4.]];
let y = array![5., 5.];
array.row_mut(0) += &y;
```

However it works if I assign the mutable slice to a temporary variable and then do the `+=` operation. the the following code works as expected ([playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5e3929360e9719488f2ab8ccf36e139d)).

```
let mut array = array![[1., 2.], [3., 4.]];
let y = array![5., 5.];
let mut z = array.row_mut(0);
z += &y;
```

Any idea what is causing the behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The left hand side of a [compound assignment expression](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/operator-expr.html#compound-assignment-expressions) must be a [place expression](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions.html#place-expressions-and-value-expressions).

> A place expression is an expression that represents a memory location. These expressions are paths which refer to local variables, static variables, dereferences (*expr), array indexing expressions (expr[expr]), field references (expr.f) and parenthesized place expressions. All other expressions are value expressions.

`array.row_mut(0)` is not a place expression, so `+=` does not work. You could instead directly call `add_assign`.

```
array.row_mut(0).add_assign(&y);
```