# Rust ndarray: Mutating axis_iters

Tags: rust, rust-ndarray

I am trying to implement somewhat **"batched" matrix multiplication in rust using `ndarray`**. Therefore I am trying to combine some `.axis_iter`s and especially update a "result"-tensors Axis-iters accordingly. For me a problem occurs already when trying something as easy as mutating the "tensor-slices" of a simple array like:

```rust
let mut c: ArrayBase<ndarray::OwnedRepr<i32>, Dim<[usize; 2]>> = array![
    [1, 2],
    [1, 2]
];
let d: ArrayBase<ndarray::OwnedRepr<i32>, Dim<[usize; 1]>> = array![1, 1];

c.axis_iter_mut(Axis(1)).for_each(|x| x = d);
```

The compiler complains at `d`'s position in the last line:

```
mismatched types
expected struct `ndarray::ArrayBase<ViewRepr<&mut i32>, _>`
   found struct `ndarray::ArrayBase<OwnedRepr<i32>, _>
```

I am **new to rust** and not sure, what to do here right now. I see that the types do not match, but I do not know how to set it up in a way that they do and `c`'s columns get updated / replaced as intended.

Dereferencing `x` with `*x` in the last line also does not work.

I also had a look at [Updating a row of a matrix in rust ndarray](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76645848/15090246) but I could not figure out how to get it to work with the `.axit_iter_mut`.

Please note, that I explicitly want this updates to happen in an `axis_iter`-way because this is needed for my actual goal of batched matmul.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a method that does what you want: [`assign()`](https://docs.rs/ndarray/latest/ndarray/struct.ArrayBase.html#method.assign):

```rust
c.axis_iter_mut(Axis(1)).for_each(|mut x| x.assign(&d));
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I had already noticed `.assign` but it did not work out. I only forgot the `mut` in front of `x`... Thanks again.